# Starting IE 11 from batch file - keeps previous tabs

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, batch-file, taskkill

I am using a batch file to kill all instances of internet explorer, and then start it again using a shortcut that is on the hard drive.  The shortcut is a HTML file that has a URL & Login information in it.  The IE version is IE 11.  The site requires the browser to be Internet Explorer. The batch file is as follows:

```
taskkill /f /t /im iexplore.exe
start /max "iexplore.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Documents\mysite.htm"
```

The HTML file has:

```
<html>
<body onload='f1.submit();'>
<form id=f1 action="http://www.awebsite.com/default.aspx" method=post>
<input id=uid name=uid type=text value=user1 style="visibility: hidden">
<input id=pwd name=pwd type=text value=pass1 style="visibility: hidden">
<input type=submit style="visibility: hidden">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, if I X out of the browser, the next time the batch file is run, it opens it in a new tab.  So, even though the "new" tab is logged in, the other old tabs are still retained when IE starts again.

How can you make IE 11 forget the last page it had open & force this to open in the first tab of a new browser each time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is more the Internet Explorer Setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A second possiblity, aside from startup IE11 options, is the crash recovery function. . As you're killing of the iexplore instances, this might be handled as a "crash".

You can find this one in *internet properties* -> *Advanced tab* -> *Browsing* -> *Enable automatic crash recovery*

[Internet options](http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Restore-Last-Session-Tabs-1.png)

I don't know if this can be done through commandline (or batch) though, if it does I'd like to know :D

Hope this helps!